# How to show that the normed space $(\ell^2, \|\cdot\|_2)$ is complete

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Show that the normed space $(\ell^2, \|\cdot\|_2)$ is complete.

I am not sure where to even start with this question. I'm quite sure it involves Cauchy and also Bolzano-Weierstrass but I'm not sure how to actually show this.

Comment: Please take a look at how I've edited the MathJax in your post; I encourage you to emulate it.

Comment: You are new here, welcome! Is this homework? It's already been three questions of yours within an hour. What is your  personal work on these questions? And finally, if one of your question is answered in a way that pleases you, note you can accept it.

Comment: DId you tried by using the definition? Where are you stuck?

Comment: [This post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147446/completeness-of-ell2-space/147449) may get you started.

Comment: These are exercises we have been given to look at for a module, i think im just struggling with the basic concepts.. As im really unsure where to even start with this question!

Answer (score 0):

For a Cauchy sequence $\{x^{(n)}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, we must show that $x^{(n)}\to x$ in $(l^2,||\cdot||_2)$ (the space of square-summable sequences under $2-$norm), which means showing $||x^{(n)}-x||_2<\epsilon$.

- The Cauchy sequence $\{ x^{(n)}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded, hence you can bound it under $l^2$ norm. Use this to conclude that the limit under $l^2$ norm is bounded, ie, $||x||_2\leq N$ for some finite value $N$.
- The fact that $x^{(n)}$ is Cauchy means we can write $||x^{(n)}-x^{(n')}||_2<\epsilon,~n,n'\geq N$. Write the sum with finite limits from $-M$ to $M$ and take the limits $n',M\to\infty$ to conclude.